# BigQuery retrieve data from sftp

Tags: google-bigquery, sftp

I have an internet facing sftp server that has regularly csv files update. Is there anyway command to have BigQuery to retrieve data from this sftp and put it into tables. Alternatively, any API or python library that support this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As for BigQuery - there's no integration I know of with SFTP.

You'll need to either:

- Create/find a script that reads from SFTP and pushes to GCS.
- Add a HTTPS service to the SFTP server, so your data can be read with the GCS transfer service (https://cloud.google.com/storage-transfer/docs/)

Answer (score 0):

Yet another 3rd party Tool supporting (S)FTP In and Out to/from GCP is Magnus - Workflow Automator which is part of [Potens.io](https://potensio.zendesk.com/) Suite - supports all BigQuery, Cloud Storage and most of Google APIs as well as multiple simple utility type Tasks like BigQuery Task, Export to Storage Task, Loop Task and many many more along with advanced scheduling, triggering, etc.. Also available at [Marketplace](https://console.cloud.google.com/marketplace/details/potens-io/potensio).

FTP-to-GCS Task accepts a source FTP URI and can transfer single or multiple files based on input to a destination location in Google Cloud Storage. The resulting uploaded list to Google Cloud Storage is saved to a parameter for later use within the Workflow. The source FTP can be of types SFTP, FTP, or FTPS.

See [here](https://potensio.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/360000650412-FTP-In-Task) for more

[image]

[image]

*Disclosure: I am GDE for Google Cloud and creator of those tools and leader on Potens team*