# Reading and writing to bigquery in gcp. What service?

Tags: database, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, dataflow

I'm creating a bigquery table where I join and transform data from several other bigquery tables. It's all written in sql and the whole query takes about 20 minutes to run and consists of several sql scripts. I'm also creating some intermediate tables before the end table is created.

Now I want to make above query more robust and schedule it and I cant decide on the tool. Alternatives I'm thinking about.

1. Make it into a dataflow job and schedule with cloud scheduler. This feels like it might be overkill because all the code is in SQL and from bq --> bq.
2. Create scheduled queries to load the data. No experience with this but seems quiet nice
3. Create a python script that executed all the sql using the BQ API. Create a cron job and schedule it to run somewhere in GCP.

Any suggestions on what would be a preferred solution?

Comment: Have you looked at using dbt?

Comment: check out https://stackoverflow.com/a/62312437/5221944 - ignore sftp part of that post - just focus on Magnus tool - it addresses a lot of concerns like those mentioned in your question

Answer (score 1):

If it's encapsulated in a single script (or even multiple) I'd schedule it through BQ. It will handle your query no different than the other options so it doesn't make sense to set up extra services for it.

Are you able to run it as a single query?

Comment: No, it will have to be several queries. That's why I'm currently running it using a python script on my local machine. Not sure if it's possible to create dependencies in scheduled queries but if it is, seems like that would be the best alternative

Comment: You can send notifications of completed scheduled queries to pubsub which means you can trigger a cloud function and chain a bunch of on-demand scheduled queries. (Haven't seen this done but should be good tutorials on it.) It's either that or setting the times with enough space apart for completion of the previous query.

If you require multiple dependencies then it's worthwhile to use an orchestration tool like Cloud Composer. If cost is a concern with Composer you can code it in a VM with Python and use Scheduler and Functions to schedule lightweight VM and turn it off once done.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. As we currently have a composer environment within the project, I'm now leaning towards running it in there and creating a DAG with every query as a task. Will also give some nice overview of the queries and possible to trigger with one click on demand

Answer (score 0):

According to my experience with GCP, both Cloud Composer and Dataflow jobs would be, as you suggested, overkill. None of these products would be serverless and would probably imply a higher economic cost because of the instances running in the background.

On the other hand, you can create scheduled queries on a regular basis (daily, weekly, etc) that are separated by a big enough time window to make sure the queries are carried out in the expected order. In this sense, the final table would be constructed correctly from the intermediate ones.

From my point of view, both executing a Python Script and sending notifications to Pub/Sub triggering a Cloud Function (as [apw-ub](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8254981/apw-ub) suggested) are also good options.

All in all, I guess the final decision should depend more on your personal preference. Please feel free to use the Google Cloud Pricing Calculator ([1](https://cloud.google.com/products/calculator)) for having an estimate of how costly each of the options would be.